Why data from mpu9255 cant be written to sdcard?
all.
Im trying to write the data from mpu9255 to sdcard, but it's always shows "Failed to open file for writing". I've checked all the wiring, and it's seems fine, and the data from mpu9255 is can be read.  Anyone know the solution?
Here is the code:
#include <MPU9255.h>  // Include MPU9255 library
#include "FS.h"
#include "SD.h"
#include <SPI.h>

MPU9255 mpu;  // Create MPU9255 object

#define SD_CS 5  // Chip select pin for the SD card

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  if (!mpu.init()) {
    Serial.println("MPU9255 initialization successful!");
  } else {
    Serial.println("MPU9255 initialization failed!");
    return;
  }

  if (!SD.begin(SD_CS)) {
    Serial.println("Card Mount Failed");
    return;
  } else {
    Serial.println("SD card initialized.");
  }

  File file = SD.open("/data.txt", FILE_WRITE);
  if (!file) {
    Serial.println("Failed to open file for writing");
    return;
  } else {
    if (file.size() == 0) {
      file.println("AX, AY, AZ, GX, GY, GZ, MX, MY, MZ");
    }
    file.close();
    Serial.println("File opened and header written.");
  }
}

void loop() {
  // Read data from MPU9255
  mpu.read_acc();
  mpu.read_gyro();
  mpu.read_mag();

  // Log data to Serial Monitor for debugging
  Serial.print("AX: ");
  Serial.print(mpu.ax);
  Serial.print(" AY: ");
  Serial.print(mpu.ay);
  Serial.print(" AZ: ");
  Serial.print(mpu.az);
  Serial.print("GX: ");
  Serial.print(mpu.gx);
  Serial.print(" GY: ");
  Serial.print(mpu.gy);
  Serial.print(" GZ: ");
  Serial.print(mpu.gz);
  Serial.print("MX: ");
  Serial.print(mpu.mx);
  Serial.print(" MY: ");
  Serial.print(mpu.my);
  Serial.print(" MZ: ");
  Serial.println(mpu.mz);

  // Write data to SD card
  logSDCard();
  delay(1000);  // Delay between reads
}

void logSDCard() {
  // Open the SD card file in append mode
  File file = SD.open("/data.txt", FILE_APPEND);
  if (!file) {
    Serial.println("Failed to open file for writing");
    return;  // Stop function execution if file cannot be opened
  }

  // Format the data string
  String dataMessage = String(mpu.ax) + ", " + String(mpu.ay) + ", " + String(mpu.az) + ", " 
                       + String(mpu.gx) + ", " + String(mpu.gy) + ", " + String(mpu.gz) + ", " 
                       + String(mpu.mx) + ", " + String(mpu.my) + ", " + String(mpu.mz);

  // Print on Serial Monitor for debugging
  Serial.print("Save data: ");
  Serial.println(dataMessage);

  // Write the data message to SD card
  file.println(dataMessage);

  // Check for write errors
  if (file.getWriteError()) {
    Serial.println("Error writing to file.");
    file.clearWriteError();  // Clear the error code.
  }

  // Close the file to save the data
  file.close();
}

Im expecting that the data that is being read from the mpu9255 sensor to be written to the sdcard, Right now it always shows "Failed to open for writing"

Reduce your sketch to a [mre], removing the MPU9255 stuff. Apparently it is not relevant for the issue.

From your code, and your comment, the SD card is clearly mounting correctly (as you do not report a failure to mount). But it will not open for writing. There are not too many things to look for here. Since it mounts, the card reader must be connected correctly with the right chip select pin, and the card itself must be viable with a viable format (it will fail to mount if you have an NTFS formatted card for example).
This leaves us with just a write-protected card, a file already open, a completely full SD card, or a badly fragmented card. So I would try using a different SD card, try using a different filename, and check that there is no physical write protection.

Have you tried these things? What happened?
